# Partial View, HTML Helper or other

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code that populates two drop down lists, it all works great in the one view “BeachSearch” but I would like to re use it in a number of other views.

```
public ActionResult BeachSearch()
{
    var db = new PeninsulaGuideEntities();

    //Populate Coastline Dropdown
    var coastlines = db.CoastLines.Select(c => new { c.CoastLineID, c.CoastLineName });
    ViewBag.CoastLineId = new SelectList(coastlines.AsEnumerable(), "CoastLineID", "CoastLineName", 0);

    //Populate Town Dropdown
    var towns = (from bf in db.Towns
                    join f in db.Beaches on bf.TownID equals f.TownFK
                    select new
                    {
                        bf.TownID,
                        bf.TownName
                    }).Distinct();

    ViewBag.TownId = new SelectList(towns.AsEnumerable(), "TownID", "TownName", 0);

    return View();
}
```

How can I reuse this code, e.g.. a Partial View or an HTML Helper? If so, where should I put the file in my file structure remembering that all the views that will use it are derived from my HomeController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view (assuming the BeachSearch method is in the HomeController) :

```
    <h2>Beaches</h2>
    @Html.Action("BeachSearch", "Home")
```

In the controller change this:

```
public ActionResult BeachSearch()
{
    ...

    return PartialView();
}
```

*The sample uses asp.net MVC3 and a razor view*

Comment: Thanks Eduardo, That worked perfectly. I +1nd you two for mentioning that the sample was in Razor too. I knew it was but for some there is a bit of confusion when dealing with MVC2 and 3. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to decorate the BeachSearch action with the `[ChildAction]` and return a partial view like following

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult BeachSearch()
{
    var db = new PeninsulaGuideEntities();

    //Populate Coastline Dropdown
    var coastlines = db.CoastLines.Select(c => new { c.CoastLineID, c.CoastLineName });
    ViewBag.CoastLineId = new SelectList(coastlines.AsEnumerable(), "CoastLineID", "CoastLineName", 0);

    //Populate Town Dropdown
    var towns = (from bf in db.Towns
                join f in db.Beaches on bf.TownID equals f.TownFK
                select new
                {
                    bf.TownID,
                    bf.TownName
                }).Distinct();

    ViewBag.TownId = new SelectList(towns.AsEnumerable(), "TownID", "TownName", 0);

    return PartialView();
}
```

Now, wherever you want to render this action method, use the following code

```
@{Html.RenderAction("TextForAction", "BeachSearch", "Controller");}
```

**NOTE**:- You don't need to make any changes to your view. Just use the above code in places where you want to render the partial view.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, I gave you a +1 because yu gave me a heads up on something, Why do we you need to add a ChildActionOnly filter to the method???

Comment: The ChildActionOnly attribute designates that the action method can only be used within a main view. It returns a PartialView to insert a partial response into the UI, rather than including a whole view. Therefore you can use to enhance your views but cannot make use of this as a standalone MVC action